Trouble installing Laravel Breeze: Encountering npm ETARGET error
When I attempted to install Laravel Breeze using the command php artisan breeze:install, I encountered an error.
(Note: I successfully ran composer require Laravel\breeze --dev and I am using Laravel 10.)
Here is the error message I received:

INFO  Installing and building Node dependencies. npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for type@module. npm ERR!
notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
C:\Users\XPRISTO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-10T06_50_35_697Z-debug-0.log

Can anyone assist me with this issue? I am trying to install the Breeze package using the method outlined in the Laravel Documentation.

what is your npm version? npm -v
